# How do I get the ObjectID associated with the authenticated Azure service principal?

Tags: c#, azure

I created an Enterprise Application in Azure AD. I'm using that to authenticate and create resources:

```
AzureCredentials creds = SdkContext.AzureCredentialsFactory.FromServicePrincipal(
    ClientId, ClientSecret, TenantId, AzureEnvironment.AzureGlobalCloud);

IAzure az = Azure.Authenticate(creds);
```

I don't know how to get the ObjectId associated with the Enterprise Application that I used to authenticate. Is there a way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [Microsoft Graph SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/sdks-overview) to do that, refer to the sample below, it calls the Microsoft Graph API - [`List servicePrincipals`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/serviceprincipal-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http), filter with `appId` i.e. `ClientId`.

```
GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient( authProvider );

var servicePrincipals = await graphClient.ServicePrincipals
    .Request().Filter("appId eq '<ClientId here>'")
    .GetAsync();
```

When using the code, choose the [authProvider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/choose-authentication-providers?tabs=CS) you want, and make sure you have [enough permission](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/serviceprincipal-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp#permissions) to call the API, it works fine on my side, the `Id` is the `ObjectId` of the service principal i.e. enterprise application.

[image]

Comment: This works. Unfortunately, I think I'm going to make the object ID a configuration parameter instead since I don't want to pull in Graph just for this and Microsoft.Graph.Auth is still pre-release plus I have an alternate scenario where I need to get the object ID for a user assigned managed identity which requires changes that I don't have permissions to make.